# How to use own environment for DDPG without gym

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, openai-gym

I'm using Keras to build a ddpg model,I followed the official instruction from here [enter link description here](https://keras.io/examples/rl/ddpg_pendulum/)

But I want to my own environment, not gym,here is my own environment:

```
class Environment1:
def __init__(self, data, history_t=90):
    self.data = data
    self.history_t = history_t
    self.reset ()

def reset(self):
    self.t = 0
    self.done = False
    self.profits = 0
    self.positions = []
    self.position_value = 0
    self.history = [0 for _ in range (self.history_t)]
    return [self.position_value] + self.history  # obs

def step(self, act):
    reward = 0

    # act = 0: stay, 1: buy, 2: sell
    if act == 1:
        self.positions.append (self.data.iloc[self.t, :]['close'])
    elif act == 2:  # sell
        if len (self.positions) == 0:
            reward = -1
        else:
            profits = 0
            for p in self.positions:
                profits += (self.data.iloc[self.t, :]['close'] - p)
            reward += profits
            self.profits += profits
            self.positions = []

    # set next time
    self.t += 1
    self.position_value = 0
    for p in self.positions:
        self.position_value += (self.data.iloc[self.t, :]['close'] - p)
    self.history.pop (0)
    self.history.append (self.data.iloc[self.t, :]['close'] - self.data.iloc[(self.t - 1), :]['close'])

    # clipping reward
    if reward > 0:
        reward = 1
    elif reward < 0:
        reward = -1

    return [self.position_value] + self.history, reward, self.done  # obs, reward, done


env = Environment1 (train)
print (env.reset ())
for _ in range (3):
    pact = np.random.randint (3)
    print (env.step (pact))
```

When I use my own environment as above,there is an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a51b38095bf0> in <module>
    179 # env = gym.make(problem)
    180 
--> 181 num_states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
    182 print("Size of State Space ->  {}".format(num_states))
    183 num_actions = env.action_space.shape[0]

AttributeError: 'Environment1' object has no attribute 'observation_space'
```

Following is the whole code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import numpy as np  # linear algebra
import pandas as pd  # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from subprocess import check_output
# print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
import time
import copy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\willi\Downloads\spyv.csv')

data = data.loc[:, ~data.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]


date_split = 377

train = data[:date_split]
test = data[date_split:]


class Environment1:

    def __init__(self, data, history_t=90):
        self.data = data
        self.history_t = history_t
        self.reset ()

    def reset(self):
        self.t = 0
        self.done = False
        self.profits = 0
        self.positions = []
        self.position_value = 0
        self.history = [0 for _ in range (self.history_t)]
        return [self.position_value] + self.history  # obs

    def step(self, act):
        reward = 0

        # act = 0: stay, 1: buy, 2: sell
        if act == 1:
            self.positions.append (self.data.iloc[self.t, :]['close'])
        elif act == 2:  # sell
            if len (self.positions) == 0:
                reward = -1
            else:
                profits = 0
                for p in self.positions:
                    profits += (self.data.iloc[self.t, :]['close'] - p)
                reward += profits
                self.profits += profits
                self.positions = []

        # set next time
        self.t += 1
        self.position_value = 0
        for p in self.positions:
            self.position_value += (self.data.iloc[self.t, :]['close'] - p)
        self.history.pop (0)
        self.history.append (self.data.iloc[self.t, :]['close'] - self.data.iloc[(self.t - 1), :]['close'])

        # clipping reward
        if reward > 0:
            reward = 1
        elif reward < 0:
            reward = -1

        return [self.position_value] + self.history, reward, self.done  # obs, reward, done


env = Environment1 (train)
print (env.reset ())
for _ in range (3):
    pact = np.random.randint (3)
    print (env.step (pact))

#above here are all my own code, under here is the code from keras

num_states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
print("Size of State Space ->  {}".format(num_states))
num_actions = env.action_space.shape[0]
print("Size of Action Space ->  {}".format(num_actions))

upper_bound = env.action_space.high[0]
lower_bound = env.action_space.low[0]

print("Max Value of Action ->  {}".format(upper_bound))
print("Min Value of Action ->  {}".format(lower_bound))


class OUActionNoise:
    def __init__(self, mean, std_deviation, theta=0.15, dt=1e-2, x_initial=None):
        self.theta = theta
        self.mean = mean
        self.std_dev = std_deviation
        self.dt = dt
        self.x_initial = x_initial
        self.reset()

    def __call__(self):
        # Formula taken from https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck_process.
        x = (
            self.x_prev
            + self.theta * (self.mean - self.x_prev) * self.dt
            + self.std_dev * np.sqrt(self.dt) * np.random.normal(size=self.mean.shape)
        )
        # Store x into x_prev
        # Makes next noise dependent on current one
        self.x_prev = x
        return x

    def reset(self):
        if self.x_initial is not None:
            self.x_prev = self.x_initial
        else:
            self.x_prev = np.zeros_like(self.mean)
            
            
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self, buffer_capacity=100000, batch_size=64):
        # Number of "experiences" to store at max
        self.buffer_capacity = buffer_capacity
        # Num of tuples to train on.
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        # Its tells us num of times record() was called.
        self.buffer_counter = 0

        # Instead of list of tuples as the exp.replay concept go
        # We use different np.arrays for each tuple element
        self.state_buffer = np.zeros((self.buffer_capacity, num_states))
        self.action_buffer = np.zeros((self.buffer_capacity, num_actions))
        self.reward_buffer = np.zeros((self.buffer_capacity, 1))
        self.next_state_buffer = np.zeros((self.buffer_capacity, num_states))

    # Takes (s,a,r,s') obervation tuple as input
    def record(self, obs_tuple):
        # Set index to zero if buffer_capacity is exceeded,
        # replacing old records
        index = self.buffer_counter % self.buffer_capacity

        self.state_buffer[index] = obs_tuple[0]
        self.action_buffer[index] = obs_tuple[1]
        self.reward_buffer[index] = obs_tuple[2]
        self.next_state_buffer[index] = obs_tuple[3]

        self.buffer_counter += 1

    # Eager execution is turned on by default in TensorFlow 2. Decorating with tf.function allows
    # TensorFlow to build a static graph out of the logic and computations in our function.
    # This provides a large speed up for blocks of code that contain many small TensorFlow operations such as this one.
    @tf.function
    def update(
        self, state_batch, action_batch, reward_batch, next_state_batch,
    ):
        # Training and updating Actor & Critic networks.
        # See Pseudo Code.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            target_actions = target_actor(next_state_batch, training=True)
            y = reward_batch + gamma * target_critic(
                [next_state_batch, target_actions], training=True
            )
            critic_value = critic_model([state_batch, action_batch], training=True)
            critic_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(y - critic_value))

        critic_grad = tape.gradient(critic_loss, critic_model.trainable_variables)
        critic_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(critic_grad, critic_model.trainable_variables)
        )

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            actions = actor_model(state_batch, training=True)
            critic_value = critic_model([state_batch, actions], training=True)
            # Used `-value` as we want to maximize the value given
            # by the critic for our actions
            actor_loss = -tf.math.reduce_mean(critic_value)

        actor_grad = tape.gradient(actor_loss, actor_model.trainable_variables)
        actor_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(actor_grad, actor_model.trainable_variables)
        )

    # We compute the loss and update parameters
    def learn(self):
        # Get sampling range
        record_range = min(self.buffer_counter, self.buffer_capacity)
        # Randomly sample indices
        batch_indices = np.random.choice(record_range, self.batch_size)

        # Convert to tensors
        state_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.state_buffer[batch_indices])
        action_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.action_buffer[batch_indices])
        reward_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.reward_buffer[batch_indices])
        reward_batch = tf.cast(reward_batch, dtype=tf.float32)
        next_state_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.next_state_buffer[batch_indices])

        self.update(state_batch, action_batch, reward_batch, next_state_batch)


# This update target parameters slowly
# Based on rate `tau`, which is much less than one.
@tf.function
def update_target(target_weights, weights, tau):
    for (a, b) in zip(target_weights, weights):
        a.assign(b * tau + a * (1 - tau))
        
        
def get_actor():
    # Initialize weights between -3e-3 and 3-e3
    last_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-0.003, maxval=0.003)

    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(num_states,))
    out = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(inputs)
    out = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(out)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer=last_init)(out)

    # Our upper bound is 2.0 for Pendulum.
    outputs = outputs * upper_bound
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model


def get_critic():
    # State as input
    state_input = layers.Input(shape=(num_states))
    state_out = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(state_input)
    state_out = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(state_out)

    # Action as input
    action_input = layers.Input(shape=(num_actions))
    action_out = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(action_input)

    # Both are passed through seperate layer before concatenating
    concat = layers.Concatenate()([state_out, action_out])

    out = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(concat)
    out = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(out)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1)(out)

    # Outputs single value for give state-action
    model = tf.keras.Model([state_input, action_input], outputs)

    return model


def policy(state, noise_object):
    sampled_actions = tf.squeeze(actor_model(state))
    noise = noise_object()
    # Adding noise to action
    sampled_actions = sampled_actions.numpy() + noise

    # We make sure action is within bounds
    legal_action = np.clip(sampled_actions, lower_bound, upper_bound)

    return [np.squeeze(legal_action)]

std_dev = 0.2
ou_noise = OUActionNoise(mean=np.zeros(1), std_deviation=float(std_dev) * np.ones(1))

actor_model = get_actor()
critic_model = get_critic()

target_actor = get_actor()
target_critic = get_critic()

# Making the weights equal initially
target_actor.set_weights(actor_model.get_weights())
target_critic.set_weights(critic_model.get_weights())

# Learning rate for actor-critic models
critic_lr = 0.002
actor_lr = 0.001

critic_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(critic_lr)
actor_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(actor_lr)

total_episodes = 100
# Discount factor for future rewards
gamma = 0.99
# Used to update target networks
tau = 0.005

buffer = Buffer(50000, 64)


# To store reward history of each episode
ep_reward_list = []
# To store average reward history of last few episodes
avg_reward_list = []

# Takes about 4 min to train
for ep in range(total_episodes):

    prev_state = env.reset()
    episodic_reward = 0

    while True:
        # Uncomment this to see the Actor in action
        # But not in a python notebook.
        # env.render()

        tf_prev_state = tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(prev_state), 0)

        action = policy(tf_prev_state, ou_noise)
        # Recieve state and reward from environment.
        state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

        buffer.record((prev_state, action, reward, state))
        episodic_reward += reward

        buffer.learn()
        update_target(target_actor.variables, actor_model.variables, tau)
        update_target(target_critic.variables, critic_model.variables, tau)

        # End this episode when `done` is True
        if done:
            break

        prev_state = state

    ep_reward_list.append(episodic_reward)

    # Mean of last 40 episodes
    avg_reward = np.mean(ep_reward_list[-40:])
    print("Episode * {} * Avg Reward is ==> {}".format(ep, avg_reward))
    avg_reward_list.append(avg_reward)

# Plotting graph
# Episodes versus Avg. Rewards
plt.plot(avg_reward_list)
plt.xlabel("Episode")
plt.ylabel("Avg. Epsiodic Reward")
plt.show()


# Save the weights
actor_model.save_weights("pendulum_actor.h5")
critic_model.save_weights("pendulum_critic.h5")

target_actor.save_weights("pendulum_target_actor.h5")
target_critic.save_weights("pendulum_target_critic.h5")
```

After I run the whole code error:

```
    AttributeError: 'Environment1' object has no attribute 'observation_space'
```

Any friend can help?It is real hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Environment1` class doesn't have the `observation_space` attribute. So to fix this you can either define it using the OpenAI gym by going through the [docs](https://gym.openai.com/docs/#spaces). If you do not want to define that, then you can also change the following lines in your DDPG code:

```py
num_states = my_num_states # instead of env.observation_space.shape[0]
print("Size of State Space ->  {}".format(num_states))
num_actions = my_num_actions # instead of env.action_space.shape[0]
print("Size of Action Space ->  {}".format(num_actions))

upper_bound = my_actions_max # instead of env.action_space.high[0]
lower_bound = my_actions_min # instead of env.action_space.low[0]
```

Here `my_num_states` is the dimension of your state vector, `my_num_actions` is the dimension of your action vector, `my_action_max` is the maximum value in your action space and `my_action_min` is the minimum value in your action space.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer!My environment is about stock trading, it has 3 actions: buy, sell, stay.So I think num_actions=3.And the trading result can be, earn money, lose money or keep same.So num_states = 3.But I’m not sure what are my_actions_max and my_actions_min, are these are the amount of stock I buy for each round.Thanks again!

Comment: Are the actions discrete in nature? In the way you have described them, it seems that they are discrete. Like you can take only one of the three discrete actions at any time and I think that you could try discrete versions of RL algorithms like Q-Learning, etc.